# Copy data from one list to another takes long time

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists: `List A (is a Dictionary)`and `List B(Data)`, each of them having two common properties `C1 and C2`. I'm trying to bring the List1 data into list 2 using linq code below but this is taking almost 9 min to execute the loop(35k records). Please assist on how to read this two list data into one list effectively without performance issue.  I have appended C1 and C2 to single property C1C2.

> List A
>
> C1|C2 |desc_1 |desc_2 |DataType
>
> 0 |1  |0  |1  |TEXT
>
> 0 |2  |0  |2  |TEXT
>
> 0 |3  |0  |3  |TEXT
>
> 0 |4  |0  |4  |TEXT
>
> 22    |1  |22 |1  |NUMERIC
>
> 22    |2  |22 |2  |NUMERIC

.

> List B
>
> App_Id    |C1 |C2 |value
>
> 12      |0    |1  |55R76
>
> 12    |0  |2  |TEST PROEPRTIES
>
> 12    |0  |3  |CHOPPER
>
> 12    |0  |4  |TEST MD
>
> 13    |0  |1  |9866FGG078
>
> 13    |0  |2  |TITLE2
>
> 13    |22 |1  |TODAY
>
> 13    |22 |2  |TEST12344

This is my code so far :

```
var query = from x in ListB
                            join y in ListA
                                on x.C1C2 equals y.C1C2
                            select y;
                //Update metadata from ListA to ListB
                foreach (var x in query)
                {
                    var itemToChange = ListB.FirstOrDefault(d => d.C1C2  == x.C1C2);
                    if (itemToChange != null)

                    itemToChange.Desc1 = x.Desc1;
                    itemToChange.Desc2 = x.Desc2;
                    itemToChange.DataType = x.DataType;
                }
```

Expeced Result:

> App_Id, C1,C2,Desc1, Desc2, DataType, Value in to one list.

Comment: What type is ListB? Is it a `List<T>` or a `Dictionary<T>`?

Comment: Also, the way you've described it in your tables, the items of `ListB` don't have any fields named `Desc1` or `Desc2`. So what exactly is happening in this loop?

Comment: suggestion, use `first` instead of `firstordefault` since they are already `joined` in the `query` and no need to check for `null`. All of the `x.C1C2` should exists in `ListB`

Comment: Without a good [mcve], it's impossible to reproduce your reported concern, never mind know for sure how to fix it. However, the `ListB.FirstOrDefault(d => d.C1C2  == x.C1C2);` statement seems clearly suspicious to me, as it turns your loop into an O(n^2) operation. As noted above, you've already done a `join` in your query, which you _could_ have used to combine the `x` and `y` records in the query, rather than forcing you to go looking for the matching element from `ListB` as you iterate over the selected elements from `ListA`.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `ListB` to dictionary - `DicB`, so it will be **O(n)** complexity:

```
var DicB = ListB.ToDictionary(x => x.C1C2, x => x);

foreach(var itemA in ListA)
{
    if(DicB.ContainsKey(itemA.C1C2))
    {
        var itemB = DicB[itemA.C1C2];
        itemB.Desc1 = itemA.Desc1;
        itemB.Desc2 = itemA.Desc2;
        itemB.DataType = itemA.DataType;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your current implementation is O(n^2), which can indeed get very slow as the data size gets large. You have essentially two nested loops: the outer `foreach`, and then an implicit loop in the `FirstOrDefault()` call (which has to scan the `ListB` collection to find the element of interest).

You're already doing a `join`, but for some reason not using it idiomatically. That is, normally when one uses a `join` query, they actually do *join* the data so that the paired elements that are found can be enumerated sequentially in O(n) time.

Lacking a complete code example in your question, it's impossible to know for sure how to fix your code, but I would expect something like this would work much better:

```cs
var query = from x in ListB
            join y in ListA
            on x.C1C2 equals y.C1C2
            select new { Source = y, Target = x };

//Update metadata from ListA to ListB
foreach (var x in query)
{
    x.Target.Desc1 = x.Source.Desc1;
    x.Target.Desc2 = x.Source.Desc2;
    x.Target.DataType = x.Source.DataType;
}
```